# Spring MVC Controller Test passing due to not finding model attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test

I have created the Home Controller below. This controller fetches the 5 dummy posts I have created in the "PostRepository" class through PostService class.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    PostService postService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getHome(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("Post", postService);

        return "home";
    }
}
```

I have implemented the following test..

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ControllerTest {

    @Test //Test the Home Controller
    public void TestHomePage() throws Exception{
        HomeController homeController = new HomeController();
        MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(homeController).build();

        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(view().name("home"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeDoesNotExist("Post"));
    }

}
```

The test has successfully passed. But the attribute should exist.

Comment: You should put a more complete code (at least your complete HomeController, the whole error message to see which line is in error,...)

Comment: @RemyG, Thanks! I have updated the post with your recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two incompatible features of Spring's testing support.

If you instantiate the controller within the test, you need to use `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup()`.

If you are using the *Spring TestContext Framework* (i.e., `@ContextConfiguration`, etc.), then you need to use `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup()`.

Thus, the following is the appropriate configuration for your test.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    PostService postService;

    @Test
    public void TestHomePage2() throws Exception {
        MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();

        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(view().name("home"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("Post",postService));
    }
}
```

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Thanks @Sam Brannen, that makes perfect sense! I was mixing both recommended methods. Loading my Spring MVC configuration & creating a controller instance w/o loading the Spring configuration. I have edited my code & removed standaloneSetup as this does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the complete code, then you are missing

`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`

Comment: This does not fix the problem, still getting the same error message. I have updated my question to include your suggestion. Thanks @Irwan Hendra